# How to fix FAILED: ParseException line 7:0 cannot recognize input near 'user' '.' 'time_zone' in selection target

Tags: hive, hue

I am currently analysing Iron man 3 tweets sentiments and getting error when I categorise the country wise tweets

Tried in both linux console and Hue hive editor

```
CREATE VIEW tweets_simple AS
SELECT          
id,
cast ( from_unixtime( unix_timestamp(concat( '2013 ', substring(created_at,5,15)), 'yyyy MMM dd hh:mm:ss')) as timestamp) ts,
text,
user.time_zone
FROM tweets_raw;
```

Errors:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 6:14 cannot recognize input near 'user' '.' 'time_zone' in selection target
```

Comment: is it running without user.time_zone?

Answer (score 0):

If column name in source table having dot like in your case user.time_zone, You can try using like this `` `user.time_zone` ``   using back-tic (`)

Else hive consider the first part before dot as database, alias of any subquery result.

Answer (score 0):

JAR was missing, actually once logout we need to run the command again other wise it will not execute, well thanks for your suggestion and time